# Storing the value NUL (ASCII) in XML

Tags: java, xml

Is it possible to save the ASCII NUL character in XML like this `<data>*NUL**NUL**NUL*</data>`?

I know I can display this value in Java using `System.out.println("\0")` and I wonder if XML can handle this value.

*My objective is to get "\0\0\0" from XML using Java

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Are you trying to make a distinction between <data/> and Null?  This might be a good place to use an attribute if that is what you are doing.

Comment: I don't know whether XML does allow "\0", but the ElementTree-Library of Python does not support it. I get *"ValueError: All strings must be XML compatible: Unicode or ASCII, no NULL bytes or control characters"*. Maybe you could use the *Base64*-Encoding to save data which contains NUL-Bytes. It is common to use it in such situations.

Comment: FYI: An XML document can be stored or transmitted in one of various character encodings. However, all of the characters, semantically, are Unicode. Also, a Java string, like "\0\0\0" is Unicode, too. Although NULL is a character that Unicode has in common with ASCII, Unicode characters descriptions do not refer to U+0000 as "ASCII NULL."

Answer (score 3):

By the [specs for 1.0](http://www.sklar.com/archives/96-XML-vs.-Control-Characters.html) it would not be allowed officially.

The ASCII NUL aka `'\0'` aka `\u0000` is a normal character in java. In C/C++ however it is used as a string terminator. So when C software would process XML it probably would detect the end of the XML text way too early.

For this java also has a solution, namely when XML is written in the UTF-8 encoding Unicode values > 127 are encoded in a multibyte sequence with 8th bit 1. `DataOutputStream.writeUTF8` writes the '\0` also as multi-byte sequence. So it is read normally, and the decoding works.

- This is not entirely strict UTF-8 that requires the *shortest* encoding.
- I am still unsure about errors in C of processing the XML DOM.

So it is not a good idea.

Also mind, **binary data** should be converted to Base64 ASCII instead. As UTF-8 is not suited for binary data.

Comment: I thing the more important question is whether *XML* does support such characters. If it would be the case, the implementations should be aware about it. But I do not think that it is supported.

Comment: @JojOatXGME you are quite right. I added a reference to that effect. +1

Answer (score 3):

NUL(U+0000) is not allowed in XML 1.0 and 1.1.

Wikipedia: [Valid characters in XML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valid_characters_in_XML#Characters_allowed_but_discouraged)

> Note that the code point U+0000, assigned to the null control
>   character, is the only character encoded in Unicode and ISO/IEC 10646
>   that is always invalid in any XML 1.0 and 1.1 document.

Answer (score 2):

These are the possibilities for what data might look like,

```
              <row>
                  <data>actual data</data>
              </row>
              <row>
                  <!--null using attr. n ="t"-->
                  <data n="t"></data>
              </row>
              <row>
                  <!--some other meaning-->
                  <data/>
              </row>
```

edit:  If you want to represent multiple nulls take the attribute route and change the attribute to represent how many nulls.

```
              <row>
                  <!--null using attr. n ="3"-->
                  <data n="3"></data>
              </row>
```

which is three nulls in the example.

edit:  This is valid XML

```
              <row>
                  <data>\0</data>
              </row>
```

Your XML processor may not like it, but there is nothing wrong with it.

Comment: As far as I understand the question, he is not talking about `null` as it is used in programming languages. I thing he want to save data which contains `NUL`. But maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: @JojOatXGME - I get that, I don't understand the difference between null data and specifying that the data is null using a character.

Comment: Yes, the null value in ASCII. Check the ASCII table and youll know what I mean.

Comment: @dbasnett I want to get the string "\0" from XML using Java.

Comment: @dbasnett A byte can have 256 different values. One of them is `NUL`. For example you may want to transmitt the contents of a file emedded in XML. A file may contains `NUL` at some positions, so you have to represent it. Such solution like describted in you answer could be extended to support such cases, but I think it is not straight forward.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear enough, but, besides "\0\0\0", I also want to get "\0\0\1" ("\1" is SOH in ASCII). Also, I will get "\\0" from `<data>\0</data>` instead of "\0".

Answer (score 2):

I have not read the standard of *XML* but since *ElementTree* of *Python* complains that it is not a valid XML-character, I think it is not supported by XML. You could implement an escape mechanism and represent `"\0"` with `"\\0"`. Another possibility is the use the common *Base64* encoding.

In Java, it may look like this:

```
// write data to element
String data = ...
element.setText(Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(data.getBytes("UTF-8")))

// read data from element
String data = new String(Base64.getDecoder().decode(element.getText())), "UTF-8")
```