# Can I make XmlSerializer in .NET 6+ accept a NULL character?

Tags: c#, xml, .net-core, .net-6.0, xml-serialization

Consider the following minimal example ([fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/g4VM5P)):

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
                    
public class Program
{
    public class C { public string S { get; set; } }
    
    public static void Main()
    {
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(C));
        C data = new C() { S = "a\0b" };
        
        using (var sw = new StringWriter())
        {
            serializer.Serialize(sw, data);
            Console.WriteLine(sw.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

In .NET Framework (4.x) and .NET 5 this code creates the following output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<C xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <S>a&#x0;b</S>
</C>
```

In .NET 6 and 7 we get an InvalidOperationException:

```
Unhandled exception. System.InvalidOperationException: There was an error generating the XML document.
 ---> System.ArgumentException: '.', hexadecimal value 0x00, is an invalid character.
   at System.Xml.XmlEncodedRawTextWriter.WriteElementTextBlock(Char* pSrc, Char* pSrcEnd)
   at System.Xml.XmlEncodedRawTextWriter.WriteString(String text)
   at System.Xml.XmlWellFormedWriter.WriteString(String text)
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializationWriter.WriteElementString(String localName, String ns, String value, XmlQualifiedName xsiType)
   at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationWriterC.Write2_C(String n, String ns, C o, Boolean isNullable, Boolean needType)
   at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationWriterC.Write3_C(Object o)
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Void** arguments, Signature sig, Boolean isConstructor)
   at System.Reflection.MethodInvoker.Invoke(Object obj, IntPtr* args, BindingFlags invokeAttr)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Serialize(XmlWriter xmlWriter, Object o, XmlSerializerNamespaces namespaces, String encodingStyle, String id)
   at Program.Main()
```

Well, since the NULL character [is not a valid character in XML](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38012034/87698), this change totally makes sense.

Unfortunately, XmlSerializer is used in a library of mine to serialize/deserialize arbitrary (serializable) .NET objects, and this is a breaking change. I don't really care whether the generated XML is "correct" or not, since it's only read by the matching deserialization method¹.

So, **is it possible to configure `XmlSerializer` to accept NULL characters in .NET 7?**

---

Footnotes:

¹ Yes, XmlSerializer can parse `&#0x;` (even in .NET 7), if you provide it with an XmlTextReader with `Normalization = false`. This is [documented behavior](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmltextreader.normalization?view=net-7.0).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you insist on creating invalid XML, you can create a custom XmlWriter with [`CheckCharacters`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlwritersettings.checkcharacters?view=net-7.0) disabled. The following example should create the same output in .NET 7 as your example code in .NET Framework (4.x) ([fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/EZ9MxH)):

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
                    
public class Program
{
    public class C { public string S { get; set; } }
    
    public static void Main()
    {
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(C));
        C data = new C() { S = "a\0b" };
        
        var settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
        settings.CheckCharacters = false;
        settings.NewLineHandling = NewLineHandling.Entitize;
        settings.Indent = true;
        
        using (var sw = new StringWriter())
        using (var xw = XmlWriter.Create(sw, settings))
        {
            serializer.Serialize(xw, data);
            Console.WriteLine(sw.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```